# NodeJS buffer.slice() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, buffer, splice

I am trying to use slice() to remove some unwanted elements from the buffer. Code goes like this:

```
function unpack (item) { // item is a buffer
    var ivlength = 16;
    if(algorithm == 'aes-128-ecb') ivlength = 0;
    var ciphertext = item.slice(ivlength, item.length);
    return ciphertext;
}
```

The console says: item.slice() is not a function. The NodeJS documentation says otherwise: [buf.slice() documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end).

I have updated NodeJS to 5.9.1 version with no improvements.

Answer (score 2):

`slice()` is what is supported, *not* s**p**lice().

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I used slice() indeed but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does `console.dir(Buffer.isBuffer(item))` show?

Comment: It says false, but `console.log(msg)` says:
`Uint8Array[188]
proto: Buffer`

Item is a product of:
`function pack (iv, ciphertext) {
 if(algorithm == 'aes-128-ecb') iv = new Buffer('');
 var item = Buffer.concat([iv, ciphertext]);
 return item;
}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem occured because I tried to use received item as a buffer parameter in the unpack() function. Before passing it to that function it was serialized and received through the socket without knowing the buffer cannot be serialized. I solved this by creating a new buffer from the received data as follows:

```
var buff = new Buffer(_msg.content);
var data = unpack(buff);
```

The function slice() works properly now.